# Cannot read property 'name' of null in ejs file (node.js )

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I'm creating an node.js web app using mongodb where comments are associated with posts.  I'm getting an error "Cannot read property 'name' of null".

```
TypeError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/YelpCamp/views/show.ejs:3
1| <% include partials/header %>
2| >> 
3| <h1><%= Post.name %></h1>
4| 
5| <img src="<%= Post.image %>">
6| 
Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

Actually this error is occured after seeding the database. Here my show route code -

```
app.get("/posts/:id", function(req, res){
    post.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(err, foundPost){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            res.render("show", {Post : foundPost});
        }
    });
});
```

And this is my show.ejs template code -

```
<% include partials/header %>
<h1><%=Post.name%></h1>
<img src= "<%= Post.image%>" >
<p> <%= Post.description %> </p>
<% include partials/footer %>
```

My Post Schema and Comment schema code -

```
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name : String,
image : String,
description : String,
comments : [
        {
            type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref : "comment"
        }
    ]
});
```

Post Schema -

```
var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
text : String,
author : String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("comment", commentSchema);
```

For some reason when I try to access show route I get the error and 
I can't seem to figure out what is causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I error occur because I haven't started mongodb server. Once I started mongo server by entering a command 'mongod' in cmd. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this `Post[0].fieldname` beacause `Post` can be array.

```
<% include partials/header %>
<h1><%=Post[0].name%></h1>
<img src= "<%= Post[0].image%>" >
<p> <%= Post[0].description %> </p>
<% include partials/footer %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have populated it with comments. A simple way to fix this will be to just drop the collection by going into mongodb shell.

you can go into mongoDB Shell by typing `mongo` in your terminal

then just head to the Database in which you have stored your comments

```
use camp_ground
```

In your case the name would be different.

Your collections can be seen by running this command `show collections`

In that list of collections, just see the name with "comments" that you created earlier

Drop this collection by running this command `db.comments.drop()`

you should get

> True

[Refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FM9Hf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error, just restart your server and when you face that error just press the back page button on chrome and refresh there. You won't face it again.